# Powershell script to uninstall all .NET (9pkgs) and Desktop Runtime (2pkgs)

Tags: .net, powershell, uninstallation

I am desperately trying to automate the uninstall of the following packages:

- .NET Host FX Resolver (x64 + x86)
- .NET Host Host (x64 + x86)
- .NET Runtime (x64 + x86)
- ASP.NET Core 6.0.18 shared framework (x64 + x86)
- ASP.NET Core 6.0.18 hosting bundle options
- Windows Desktop Runtime (x64 + x86)

I don't want to just run the new exe files and upgrade, potentially leaving registry entries, msi's, exe's, and temp files on the hdd. I want to do it correctly, uninstall the application, then install the newest application. Just to note this is an air-gapped network so install of apps takes the ole' sneakernet on dvd from online pc to offline pc.
I have created a .csv file with the following columns; action, appname, dir, arguments.

I use action because I also call new updated .NET packages, google chrome, Firefox, and acrobat reader after the uninstalls complete.

I have captured installed packages and directory \ filename.msi from the “wmic product list” command.

My script is a foreach loop through the csv file. The uninstalls appear to be successful, no errors are returned while it runs.
Then an if statement if action is uninstall then run

```
`Msiexec.exe /X $dir $arguments`
```

After it runs, the .NET apps still remain in ‘Add or Remove Programs’

So I tried running directly in PS:

```
`Get-Package -Name “6.0.18” -AllVersions | Uninstall-Package
```

Appeared to run successfully.
But, the App remains in ‘Add or Remove Programs’

So I tried running in PS:

Uninstall-Package command

I tried the dotnet-core-uninstall-1.6.0 application but it didn't list all the packages that I see with the

wmic product list

command, I don't want to install an application to then have to uninstall it.. (if I can help it)

Comment: `an air-gapped network` in that case create [a self-contained deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained) and don't try to uninstall the existing runtimes, which could break other installed applications